# regular expression with jquery and accented characters

Tags: jquery, regex, input, expression

i'm looking for a regular expression to validate an input :
in France, we can use accented characters in name, and i don't find anything i can use.
please, can you help me to find how to do a regular expression for:
-any letter
-any accented letter
-spaces
- and the sign "-" (without quotes)

i've try something like but it don't seem to be working..
var regealpha =/[^A-Za-z0-9ÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ]/;

thx for help (and sorry for my poor english... i'm a froggy ^^ )

Comment: it's not clear what exactly do you need to match. Can you give us an example?

Comment: thanks a lot for all your answers!!! they are all good, but my problem is : who got numbers in his name??? (R2D2 perhaps, or C-3PO...). all i need to test, it's if there all kind of characters we can find in a name : [a-z][A-Z] space (composed name) dash (composed name) sp the best way for me is : /^[a-zA-Z ',-]+$/

Thanks ALL

Comment: Edit your question to contain some examples. Include both correct, and incorrect names.

Comment: See 'EDIT' below. I hope I understand you correctly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript doesn't seem to have good internationalization options. The symbol \w will give you  all [A-Za-z0-9_], but you'll need to stipulate your own chars in addition to this.

You seem to be quite close. The following regex should work for you:

```
/[\wÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ]/g
```

See it working at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/jameswiseman/3H2mJ/1/

You'll see that the regex replaces everything in the input string `"0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ"` with 'z'.

**EDIT**

I think this is what you need:

```
/[^a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ]/
```

It will tell you if there are characters NOT in the above set. So

```
var myRegex = /[^a-zA-ZÀÁÂÃÄÅàáâãäåÒÓÔÕÖØòóôõöøÈÉÊËèéêëÇçÌÍÎÏìíîïÙÚÛÜùúûüÿÑñ]/;
"C3P0".test(myRegex ); //returns true --> Report Error!
"kangun".test(myRegex ); //returns false --> OK :-)
"kàngun".test(myRegex ); //returns false --> OK :-)
```

Also have a look at [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jameswiseman/3H2mJ/9/)

I know it is long, but if that is what is needed then then you should use it.

Comment: nice but.. too long and i don't need numbers in a name or surname... :)

Comment: thx but i don't need numbers in a name or surname, i've not been good to explain what i need (i dont write english fluently.. really not...)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to use `\p{L}` ([as described here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/refunicode.html)), which matches a unicode letter.

Comment: @levu, does JavaScript support this?

Comment: "No Unicode support, except for matching single characters with" (http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html) -> should be possible

Comment: @levu, I tested for `\p{L}` [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html) on Firefox and it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: i've used 
var regealpha =/^[a-zA-Z ',-]+$/;